# Why callback functions are not called in Android Facebook Login?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, android-facebook

There is no any Log.w is appear in Logcat after logged in, why?

**This Code inside onCreateView in LoginFragment**

```
CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
fragmentLoginBinding.fragmentLoginFacebookLoginOriginal.setFragment(this);
LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < LoginResult > () {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        Log.w(Tag, "S");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.w(Tag, "C");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(@NonNull FacebookException e) {
        Log.w(Tag, "E - " + e.getMessage());
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing onActivityResult hook:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```